# No Reverse Match when calling url from html file - Django

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to call my url by using the following in one of my html templates -

```
<a href="{% url 'socialx:index' %}">
```

My apps urls.py file looks like this  -

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^socialx/', include('socialx.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

And the root urls.py file is like this -

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^socialx/', include('socialx.urls'), name='socialx'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

When navigating to the app via browser I get the following error -

> > NoReverseMatch at /socialx/  'socialx' is not a registered namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)

I think that when you include the url in `urls.py` you need to add a namespace

```
 url(r'^socialx/', include('socialx.urls', namespace="socialx")),
```

And make sure that the url for going to the index page has a `name=index`.

See if that helps.

Comment: already tried the namespace but then it complains the following  - url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'

Comment: I had a typo, the `namespace` should be inside the `include()`, made an edit, does that work?